# Python Error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, error-handling

I am using an automation framework and I am getting random error after many iterations which is as follows. Can someone help me understand what this could correspond to !!

```
_os.environ['PATH'] = r'C:\DAL;' + _os.environ['PATH']
  File "c:\Python26\lib\os.py", line 420, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Function Call where it fails:

function:

```
    plugin_xml_file_name = plugin_name
else:
    plugin_xml_file_name = plugin_path + "\\" + plugin_name
#

_os.environ['PATH'] = r'C:\Intel\DAL;' + _os.environ['PATH']
_os.environ['PATH'] = r'C:\intel\dal;' + _os.environ['PATH']
_os.environ['PATH'] = _lakemore_path + ';' + _os.environ['PATH']
_os.environ['PATH'] = plugin_path + ';' + _os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: How long is `os.environ['PATH']` by this stage?

Comment: I am not sure . Is there any way to dump out that information? Or clear if it exceeds some threshold ?

Comment: What is the rest of the traceback? It is impossible to tell what is extending the path here.

Comment: It traces back to this function .. Is there any checkers that i can include here to make sure it doesnt exceed limit.

Comment: How often is that function called?

Comment: During each run .. It fails after say I call it 80th time or so ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating too long a path and the OS no longer accepts a longer environment variable.

Extend the path only *once*. Test for the presence of the paths you are adding:

```
path = _os.environ['PATH'].split(_os.pathsep)
for extra in (r'C:\Intel\DAL', r'C:\intel\dal', _lakemore_path, plugin_path):
    if extra not in path:
        _os.environ['PATH'] = _os.pathsep.join(extra, _os.environ['PATH'])
```

This code only adds new elements if not already present.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more `"/"` in the last `"/"` of path for example: 
`open('C:\Python34\book.csv')` to `open('C:\Python34\\\book.csv')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avoid including special characters like \a, \b, \t, \n, \r in your directory path. Instead use double slash whenever neccessary. Like \a, \b, \t, \n, \r.

For example  FILEPATH: `E:\android\new_dir\raw_data\books\Harry.csv` should be written as 
`E:\\android\\new_dir\\raw_data\\books\Harry.csv`